# Improve performance of apps script function that deletes duplicate rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for means to optimize my code. It currently takes 20 minutes to run.

I've already read "Best Practices" but I don't really know how to use `getValues()` and `setValues()`.

Here is my current code for deleting duplicate rows:

```
function test(){
  var nom_fichier_tlb = "Bloc2021";
  var fileId= DriveApp.getFilesByName(nom_fichier_tlb).next().getId();
  var sheet = SpreadSheet.openById(fileId).getSheets()[0];
  var lig = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var jj = 2;jj<lig;jj++){
    var valVerif1 = sheet.getRange(jj,1).getValue();
    var valVerif2 = sheet.getRange(jj-1,1).getValue();
    if(valVerif1 == valVerif2){
      sheet.deleteRow(jj);
    }
    var valVerif3 = sheet.getRange(jj,4).getValue();

// FonctionsUtiles.right is my equivalent function for Right function in VBA
// FonctionsUtiles.trim is my equivalent function for Trim function in VBA

    if (FonctionsUtiles.right(valVerif3,1) == " "){ 
      sheet.getRange(jj,4) .setValue(FonctionsUtiles.trim(valVerif3));  
    }
    if (valVerif1 == ""){
      var valVerif4 = sheet.getRange(jj+1,1).getValue();
      if (valVerif4 == ""){
        Logger.log("toast");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your current code only deletes duplicate rows that are in consecutive rows. Is that what you want? Are the rows sorted by column A? The lower part of the code seems superfluous. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes my rows are sort by Column A, that's why I want  to delete duplicates rows that are consecutive !

Answer (score 1):

The code runs slowly because it reads every row separately. To make it faster, read the data with one `Range.getValues()` call, process it, and write it back with one `Range.setValues()` call. That will make the code run in seconds rather than minutes.

In the event you have formatted the rows individually and do not want to lose the association between a row and its format, continue using `Sheet.deleteRow()` instead of using `Range.setValues()`, like this:

```
function deleteConsecutiveDuplicateRows() {
  const keyIndex = 0; // column where you want to compare values; zero-indexed -- A = 0, B = 1, C = 2...
  const file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Bloc2021').next();
  const sheet = SpreadSheet.openById(file).getSheets()[0];
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const rowsToDelete = [];
  data.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    if (!rowIndex) {
      return;
    }
    const key = row[keyIndex].trim();
    const keyAbove = data[rowIndex - 1][keyIndex].trim();
    if (key && key === keyAbove) {
      rowsToDelete.push(rowIndex + 1);
    }
  });
  deleteRows_(sheet, rowsToDelete);
}

/**
* Deletes from a sheet the rows whose row numbers are given in an array.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet A spreadsheet sheet where to delete rows.
* @param {Number[]} rowsToDelete The rows to delete, identified by 1-indexed row numbers.
* @return {Number} The count of delete operations done, i.e., number of the consecutive row runs deleted from the sheet.
*/
function deleteRows_(sheet, rowsToDelete) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 23 July 2020
  const runLengths = getRunLengths_(rowsToDelete.sort((a, b) => a - b));
  for (let i = runLengths.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sheet.deleteRows(runLengths[i][0], runLengths[i][1]);
  }
  return runLengths.length;
}

/**
* Counts consecutive numbers in an array and returns a 2D array that
* lists the first number of each run and the number of items in each run.
*
* The numbers array [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 5, 4] will get
* the result [[1, 3], [5, 1], [8, 2], [11, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1]].
*
* For best results, sort the numbers array like this:
* const runLengths = getRunLengths_(numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
* Note that duplicate values in numbers will give duplicates in result.
*
* @param {Number[]} numbers The numbers to group into runs.
* @return {Number[][]} The numbers grouped into runs, or [] if the array is empty.
*/
function getRunLengths_(numbers) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 31 May 2021
  if (!numbers.length) {
    return [];
  }
  return numbers.reduce((accumulator, value, index) => {
    if (!index || value !== 1 + numbers[index - 1]) {
      accumulator.push([value]);
    }
    const lastIndex = accumulator.length - 1;
    accumulator[lastIndex][1] = (accumulator[lastIndex][1] || 0) + 1;
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}
```

Using `Sheet.deleteRow()` instead of using `Range.setValues()` will make the code run slower, but it will still be several times faster than your current implementation.

It is unclear whether the script is *bound* to a spreadsheet (that is, you entered the code in a spreadsheet through **Tools > Script editor**), or if you have a standalone script file (that is, you created the script file in Drive.) If the former, you do not need to use the `DriveApp` call but can replace the `const file` and `const sheet` lines with a simpler call that gets a sheet in the current spreadsheet, like this:

`const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`